# "AttributeError" And PrimaryKeyRelatedField in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am fairly new to the DRF and
I'm following DRF's officials tutorial.

Here are two versions of `UserSerializer` class from `snippet/serializers.py` file. `snippet` is the application name.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippet = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username','snippet')
```

It throws the below error when I try to access this URL.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/
```

Error:

```
AttributeError at /users/
type object 'User' has no attribute 'snippet'
```

when I wrote as below then there were no errors at all.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username',)
```

It has to be something with PrimaryKeyRelatedField. Plese tell me what it is.?
And why is it affecting results. If you find my question poor then Please Don't degrade it and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use snippets not snippet, try with

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username','snippets')
```

Comment: my application name is snippet, NOT snippets.

Comment: its not related to app name , its all about related name can you paste your snippet model

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at your snippets/models.py

```
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')
```

The thing you missed is related_name argument.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

related_name argument on related model ForeignKey should match both "field name" of you serializer also be inside fields tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing this

```
class snippetSerializer(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField, serializers.ModelSerialier):
    class Meta:
       model = Snippet
       fields = '__all__'



class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   snippets = snippetSeriazlier(many=True, queryset=Snippet.objects.all())

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('id', 'username','snippets')
```